# Prevent user registration based on blacklists in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, email, web, devise

Is there a way to create a blacklist to disallow certain users from signing up by filter through their parameters during the registration process?

The idea is to prevent users that use displosable email addresses (e.g. 10minutemail) from signing up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a gem for that:

> https://github.com/lisinge/valid_email2

Install it and add:

```
validates :email, email: { mx: true, disposable: true }
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure of a gem but I think it's pretty simple to roll your own. Just place a before_filter that calls up a method :permitted?

You could use a table on the db or a yaml file depending on your needs. - Use yaml file if the contents are statics (also it's much faster)

in the permitted method check use a regex to check if it matches

```
def permitted?
 config=YAML.load_file('file.yml')
 config.each do |domain|
   email.match(domain)
end
```

You can use different regex to do the matches

Comment: you will have a hard time keeping this list up to date. A well maintained Gem takes care of that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is JavaScript solution: https://github.com/AppBeat-io/JavaScript

Usage example:

```
AppBeat.Email.isDisposable('something@sharklasers.com'); //returns true
AppBeat.Email.isDisposable('something@mailinator.com'); //returns true
AppBeat.Email.isDisposable('   something@mailinator.com   '); //returns true
AppBeat.Email.isDisposable('@mailinator.com'); //returns true
AppBeat.Email.isDisposable('mailinator.com'); //returns true
AppBeat.Email.isDisposable('unknown-domain.some-domain'); //returns false
AppBeat.Email.isDisposable('something@unknown-domain.some-domain'); //returns false
AppBeat.Email.isDisposable('something@gmail.com'); //returns false (whitelisted)
AppBeat.Email.isDisposable('something@outlook.com'); //returns false (whitelisted)
```